# What is the Python equivalent of Perl's 'if exists' for hashes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm writing a script for work, and need to be able to create a hash of arrays that will check to see if a key exists in the hash (or dictionary), and if it does I will roll up some values from the new line into the existing hash values.  Here is my code in Perl, what would be the translation in Python?

```
if (exists($rollUpHash{$hashKey}))
        {
          say("Same key found, summing up!")
          $rollUpHash{$hashKey}[14] += $lineFields[14];
          $rollUpHash{$hashKey}[15] += $lineFields[15];
          $rollUpHash{$hashKey}[16] += $lineFields[16];
          $rollUpHash{$hashKey}[17] += $lineFields[17];
          $rollUpHash{$hashKey}[24] += $lineFields[24];
          push @{$rollUpHash{$hashKey}}, $sumDeduct_NonDeduct_ytd;
          # print %rollUpHash;
        }
      else
        {
          $rollUpHash{$hashKey} = \@lineFields;
        }
```

Comment: You might also want to look at a collections.defaultdict https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Comment: Note that `exists` is completely superfluous in that code. `$rollUpHash{$hashKey}` is either undefined (false) or a reference to an array (true), so `if ($rollUpHash{$hashKey})` is sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

If you're just checking if the key exists, you can do `if "key" in your_dictionary`

Edit:

To handle the unintended second part of your question, about adding the new value to the array, you can do something like this

```
# -1 will give you the last item in the list every time
for key, value in nums.iteritems():
    nums[key].append(value[-1]+value[-1])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this as well

```
rollUpHash.get(key, None)
```

If the key exists then the function return the value of this key, else the function will return whatever you assigned as the default value (second parameter)

```
if rollUpHash.has_key(hashkey):
    print "Same key found, summing up!"
    rollUpHash[hashkey][14] += lineFields[14]
    ...
    ...
    rollUpHash[hashkey].append(sumDeduct_NonDeduct_ytd)
else:
    rollUpHash[hashkey] = lineFields
```

Comment: So if I want to add the rest of the line as a list to my dictionary using key as the key, how would that look?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking, can you elaborate? @flybonzai

Comment: Sorry, my question wasn't very clear.  I essentially was trying to figure out how to create my dictionary so that my key is a concatenated name and my row is the value.  Figured it out:)